# jscrollpane adding horizontal mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, horizontal-scrolling, jquery-jscrollpane

made this horizontal jscrollpane with images. 
selector: `.scroll-pane`
multiple scrolls on the same page.

this is how I call it: `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();`

Now I want to add a horizontal mouse wheel to it (so, to scroll horizontally, by using horizontal scroll - mac pad, or a mouse with horizontal scroll), so I made this:

```
var api = element.data('jsp');
element.bind(
  'mousewheel',
  function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY)
  {
   api.scrollByX(delta);
     return false;
 }
);
```

and it works good, but just for the first selector + all the rest divs do not have a scrollbar anymore.

Could I add something like a *each* to it?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the working solution and tested in moz & chrome

```
$('.scroll-pane').each(function(){
var scrollPane = $(this).jScrollPane();
var api = scrollPane.data('jsp'); 
scrollPane.bind( 
    'mousewheel',
    function (event, delta, deltaY) 
    { 
        api.scrollByY(delta*-50);
        return false;
    } 
); 
});
```

Comment: why `scrollByY`, when `scrollByX`? =)